# C# variable never changes even when set

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I'm making a small game in MonoGame C# and I'm using Visual Studio's built-in settings manager (Settings.settings) and I have a float called Volume in the user scope with the value set to 0.5. In my code, I load the value into the XNA `MediaPlayer` class like this:

```
MediaPlayer.Volume = Settings.Default.Volume;
Console.WriteLine("Volume loaded at " + Settings.Default.Volume);
```

This should set `MediaPlayer.Volume` from it's default of 1f to 0.5f, but instead it changes to 8? I haven't touched any volume settings before trying this so I have no idea where 8 is coming from. Also, it instantly changes back to 8 whenever I try and assign something else to it. The only way I've got it to work was constantly setting the value to 0.5 in the main loop (which is, of course, a terrible solution).

As I said, I have no idea what is causing this so I don't know what code to include in my question. However, I can point you in the right direction: [My GitHub](http://github.com/Pyroglyph/Dual)

`MediaPlayer.Volume` is first set in `Main.cs:106` and my (temporary) volume changing code is at `Main.cs:127`.

That's all I know. Any ideas?

Comment: Per [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.mediaplayer.volume.aspx), `MediaPlayer.Volume` can only be a value between 0.0f and 1.0f... so where are you observing it as 8?

Comment: Check your setting, whether it's set to User scope. If so, then it will only take a default value from your setting, thereafter it will come from the users local appdata setting. If it's set to Application scope, then it will come from the app's config file setting, after build. Watch your Volume value pre and post setting in debug to see what's going on.

Comment: @ManoDestra It's always 8 no matter when I check. It like there is something setting it to 8 every frame.

Comment: @CharlesMager I apologise for not being clear, `Properties.Settings.Default.Volume` is always 8. The `MediaPlayer.Volume` is 1 (as it's clamped).

Comment: Change your property setting then to be the correct data type and set it to an appropriate value. And bear in mind what I stated above regarding the User and Application scope of variables in Settings. If it's User scope, then you'll have to clear out the files from your AppData directory. If it's in Application scope, then you can amend the value in app.config after it is built. The value that you set in Settings is the DEFAULT value for both. It can be amended thereafter, either in app.config or AppData.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look through your [repo](https://github.com/Pyroglyph/Dual/blob/master/Dual/Settings.cs).

Your variables in SettingsData should be [protected](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a.aspx) so that Settings inherits them properly. Then it should be default to 0.5f as you expect. The way you have it, Settings does not inherit and just creates its own property of Volume.

As noted in the comments something in your config.xml is going to be setting it to 8. I suggest you save your volume as a whole int from 0-100.

I suspect in your config file 8 is actually a float that is stored in an incorrect format, ie 0,8. Your [serializer](https://github.com/Pyroglyph/Dual/blob/master/Dual/SerializeConfig.cs) does not write as [invariable culture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture(v=vs.110).aspx) so when you read a "float" back in from config that is 0,8 (instead of expected 0.8) then your engine ends up saving it as 8.

Either start saving as invariant culture or I suggest saving it as a whole int from 0-100 and conveting it during load.

```
_volume = 50;
MediaPlayer.Volume = _volume / 100f; // Volume is now correctly 0.5f.
```

Comment: I did what you said about storing the Volume using an int instead of a float. However, I'm pretty sure I need to write to the variables in SettingsData to serialize them, so wouldn't making them protected stop me from writing to them?

Comment: Also, I moved to serializing my own settings because I couldn't get the VS settings thing working. The 8 problem isn't there anymore.

Comment: Yea I think you are best writing to your own config.ini file or something similar (config.ini seems to be the norm among games). Look at my link for protected, it basically means "I have this variable but also so do my child classes".